# Life after death?

Tags: product-recommendation, death, afterlife

Can anyone direct me to a book or commentary on Jewish thoughts on what happens after death, and the evolution of those ideas. I understand that Judaism is centered on how to live life, but from I can read is somewhat obscure or absent in discussing an afterlife. My Christian friends often asked me, what do Jews believe in after death?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7805/existence-of-heaven-and-hell

Comment: See [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/282508/jewish/What-Happens-After-We-Die.htm). This follows the Ramban. Note that this isn't the only Jewish view on the question. See [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38246/why-is-resurection-of-the-dead-a-fundamental-of-faith-according-to-the-rambam).

Comment: see the book gesher hachaim

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Journey to Heaven: Exploring Jewish Views of the Afterlife](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9655240479).  It's on my to read list, but haven't gotten to it yet so your best bet is to read the amazon reviews.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Ordinarily, i'd agree, but this is a [product-recommendation], so the title plus a link is an answer.